# What is the dependency I need to get jsonpath matching to work with Spring mock mvc?

Tags: json, spring, junit, hamcrest, mockmvc

I’m using Hamcrest 2.0.0.0 and trying to get json-path matching to work using Spring (v 3.2.11.RELEASE)’s mockmvc framework.  I have this in my JUnit (v 4.11) test

```
    mockMvc.perform(get("/api/users/" + id))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(id)));
```

and I have these dependencies …

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-hamcrest</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

but I get the below error.  What is the correct depencency/version list that I need to get the json-path matching to work?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.compile(Ljava/lang/String;[Lcom/jayway/jsonpath/Filter;)Lcom/jayway/jsonpath/JsonPath;
    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.<init>(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:54)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.JsonPathResultMatchers.<init>(JsonPathResultMatchers.java:43)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath(MockMvcResultMatchers.java:146)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.resources.ZincDataControllerIT.testGetInfoForTeacher(ZincDataControllerIT.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am currently using json-path-assert (0.9.1) in a gradle project like this

```
testCompile 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:0.9.1'
```

so in maven try something like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

It should pull all the transitive dependencies too, although I noticed that jsonpath depends on Hamcrest v1.3

Comment: Oh you meant version 0.9.1 instad of 2.2.0?  Version 0.9.1 works.  For posterity, I would update your answer to remove "<version>2.2.0</version>" as a dependency and include "<version>0.9.1</version>" instead.

Comment: Did you remove the Hamcrest 2.0 dependency? Try that too